# ¿Cómo arreglo el problema con el contador de aciertos en un juego?

Tags: dev-c++

Recientemente modifiqué este programa para que, de un listado de palabras, tomara una al azar para jugar. Esto es un juego del ahorcado que me pidieron hace tiempo.

El problema está en los contadores de las palabras acertadas y repetidas. Cuando introduzco una letra diferente a la primera por segunda vez, este se suma al de los aciertos. También hay un problema con el mensaje. Podrán entender mejor cuando vean el programa.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo, déjenlo en los comentarios, será de gran ayuda. (El problema empieza desde el FOR REPETIDOS)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char rep[100],temporal[100];
    char pal;
    char *palabra[]={"ambiente","cuidado","ecosistema","naturaleza","conservacion","recursos","equilibrio","forestacion","purifica","tierra","vida","ecologico","animales","ambiental","reciclaje","atmosfera","diversidad","energia"};
    char *frase;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int longitud,i,j,inicial,acertado=0,temp=0,oportunidades=5;
    int repetido=0,gano=0;

    cout<<" JUEGO DEL AHORCADO"<<endl; 
    for(int v=0;v<=1;v++)
    {
        frase=palabra[rand()%18];   //Guarda un palabra al azar de las 18 existentes
    }

   system("cls");


    longitud = 0;   //Variables utilizadas para longitud de la palabra
    inicial = 0;
    j = 0;

    rep[0] = ' ';
    rep[1] = '\0';


    do { //Hacer todo hasta que las oportunidades(Vidas del juego) se acaben o adivine la palabra
                system("cls");
        temp=0;

        if(inicial == 0) {      //Calcula cuantas letras hay en la palabra con la funcion "strlen" y dependiendo de ello imprime los guiones bajos
         for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++) {
          if(frase[i] == ' ') {
            temporal[i] = ' ';
             longitud++;
          }
          else {
             temporal[i] = '_';       
             longitud++;
          }
         }
        }

        inicial = 1;

        temporal[longitud] = '\0';
        //FOR REPETIDOS

        for(i=0;i<=1;i++) { //For para cuando se repite la letra, empieza si se introduce la misma letra 2 veces
           if(rep[i] == pal) {          //Ejemplo Palabra casa:
            repetido = 1;               //  _ _ _ _    <----------Ingresa "a" el usuario  REPETIDO=0                    
                                        //  _ a _ a    <----------Ingresa "a"             
          }                             //  _ a _ a    <----------REPETIDO =1
          else {
           repetido = 0;    //Si se introduce otra letra no pasa nada
         }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {                 //For para contar los ACIERTOS 
         for(i=0;i<=strlen(frase);i++) {
            if(frase[i] == pal ) {
             temporal[i] = pal;
              acertado++;
              temp=1;
            }
          }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) { 
         if(temp == 0) {
           oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
           }    //Si la letra es diferente y no es una repetitiva ni tampoco es un acierto se le quita una oportunidad
        }
        else {
         printf("Ya se ha introducido este caracter");
         printf("\n\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(i=0;i<strlen(temporal);i++) {
         printf(" %c ",temporal[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        if(strcmp(frase,temporal) == 0) {
            gano = 1;
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Letras Acertadas: %d",acertado);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Oportunidades Restantes: %d",oportunidades);
        printf("\n");


        rep[j] = pal;//Guarda el valor de "pal"(Letra que introduce el usuario) en un arreglo
        j++;

        if (oportunidades==0)
        {
           break;
        }

        printf("Introduzca una letra:");
        scanf("\n%c",&pal);

    }while(oportunidades != 0); //Hasta que no haiga oportunidades o adivine la palabra imprime:


    if(gano) {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enhorabuena, has ganado.");
    }
    else {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Has perdido.");
        cout<<"La palabra era: "<<frase;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: ¿CUál es el problema con el mensaje?

Answer (score 0):

Te he arreglado el código (lo tienes más abajo) pero te explico la parte importante:

```
//FOR REPETIDOS
        repetido = 0; 

        for(i=0;i<nrepetidos;i++) { //For para cuando se repite la letra, empieza si se introduce la misma letra 2 veces
           if(rep[i] == pal) {          //Ejemplo Palabra casa:
            repetido = 1;               //  _ _ _ _    <----------Ingresa "a" el usuario  REPETIDO=0                    
                                        //  _ a _ a    <----------Ingresa "a"             
          }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {                 //For para contar los ACIERTOS 
            for(i=0;i<=strlen(frase);i++) {
                if(frase[i] == pal ) {
                    temporal[i] = pal;
                    acertado++;
                    temp=1;
                }
            }
            if(temp == 0) {
                oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
            }    //Si la letra es diferente y no es una repetitiva ni tampoco es un acierto se le quita una oportunidad

            nrepetidos++;
        } else {
         printf("Ya se ha introducido este caracter");
         printf("\n\n");
        }
```

Aparte de reordenar un poco los if solo por claridad en el código, lo único que he añadido es una variable `nrepetidos`, que se aumenta cada vez que la letra introducida es nueva. La utilizo para recorrer el array de repetidos hasta la última letra introducida. En tu código original el FOR REPETIDOS era este: `for(i=0; i<=1; i++)` por lo que solo comprobaba si el caracter introducido era uno de los dos primeros. Si era posterior no lo contaba como repetido.

Imagino que llevas poco tiempo programando, pero te recomiendo aprender sobre buenas prácticas de programación, porque el código es un poco enrevesado. Sobre todo cuida las tabulaciones y espacios, porque al estar todo más claro, tú mismo te darás cuenta antes de los fallos.

Aquí tienes el código completo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char rep[100],temporal[100];
    char pal;
    char *palabra[]={"ambiente","cuidado","ecosistema","naturaleza","conservacion","recursos","equilibrio","forestacion","purifica","tierra","vida","ecologico","animales","ambiental","reciclaje","atmosfera","diversidad","energia"};
    char *frase;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int longitud,i,j,inicial,acertado=0,temp=0,oportunidades=5;
    int repetido=0,gano=0, nrepetidos = 0;

    cout<<" JUEGO DEL AHORCADO"<<endl; 
    for(int v=0;v<=1;v++)
    {
        frase=palabra[rand()%18];   //Guarda un palabra al azar de las 18 existentes
    }

   system("cls");


    longitud = 0;   //Variables utilizadas para longitud de la palabra
    inicial = 0;
    j = 0;

    rep[0] = ' ';
    rep[1] = '\0';


    do { //Hacer todo hasta que las oportunidades(Vidas del juego) se acaben o adivine la palabra
                system("cls");
        temp=0;

        if(inicial == 0) {      //Calcula cuantas letras hay en la palabra con la funcion "strlen" y dependiendo de ello imprime los guiones bajos
         for(i=0;i<strlen(frase);i++) {
          if(frase[i] == ' ') {
            temporal[i] = ' ';
             longitud++;
          }
          else {
             temporal[i] = '_';       
             longitud++;
          }
         }
        }

        inicial = 1;

        temporal[longitud] = '\0';
        //FOR REPETIDOS
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        repetido = 0; 

        for(i=0;i<nrepetidos;i++) { //For para cuando se repite la letra, empieza si se introduce la misma letra 2 veces
           if(rep[i] == pal) {          //Ejemplo Palabra casa:
            repetido = 1;               //  _ _ _ _    <----------Ingresa "a" el usuario  REPETIDO=0                    
                                        //  _ a _ a    <----------Ingresa "a"             
          }
        }

        if(repetido == 0) {                 //For para contar los ACIERTOS 
            for(i=0;i<=strlen(frase);i++) {
                if(frase[i] == pal ) {
                    temporal[i] = pal;
                    acertado++;
                    temp=1;
                }
            }
            if(temp == 0) {
                oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
            }    //Si la letra es diferente y no es una repetitiva ni tampoco es un acierto se le quita una oportunidad

            nrepetidos++;
        } else {
         printf("Ya se ha introducido este caracter");
         printf("\n\n");
        }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        printf("\n");

        for(i=0;i<strlen(temporal);i++) {
         printf(" %c ",temporal[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        if(strcmp(frase,temporal) == 0) {
            gano = 1;
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("Letras Acertadas: %d",acertado);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Oportunidades Restantes: %d",oportunidades);
        printf("\n");


        rep[j] = pal;//Guarda el valor de "pal"(Letra que introduce el usuario) en un arreglo
        j++;

        if (oportunidades==0)
        {
           break;
        }

        printf("Introduzca una letra:");
        scanf("\n%c",&pal);

    }while(oportunidades != 0); //Hasta que no haiga oportunidades o adivine la palabra imprime:


    if(gano) {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enhorabuena, has ganado.");
    }
    else {
                printf("\n\n");
        printf("Has perdido.");
        cout<<"La palabra era: "<<frase;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hola José Delgado, muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de arreglarlo todo, no me había cuenta del error, es cierto no se mucho de programación pero estoy empezando hago muchos ejercicios que me encuentro por Internet, pero cuando me falla uno y se me acaban las ideas y las búsquedas recurro a esto, lastima que muchos solo publiquen su código esperando a que les resuelvan el trabajo. Si y también gracias por la recomendación de mejorar la apariencia del código, creí que se veía bien así.

Comment: Solo un pequeño fallo que me di cuenta, cuando introduzco una segunda letra diferente a la primera por segunda vez, esta se suma igual. No obstante, gracias por ayuda, con este avance me conformo

Comment: @Nathan Es una buena estrategia de aprendizaje. ¿Podrías indicar más detalles del fallo que comentas? Yo estuve haciendo pruebas y no detecté nada pero si me dices cuando ocurre el fallo puedo intentar revisarlo.